# Check Coockies created by the server not by the user

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I was creating a login system but I ran into an issue. I have to use PHP COOKIES. A cookie is created when a user enters the correct username and password. "user=22" or "user=23" etc. But a user can go to the console panel and create this cookie themselves with document.cookie.

isset($_COOKIE["user"]) returns true even if the cookie is created by user in console panel. So, I have to check the cookies created by the server. Is there a way to do it? Let me know if there is a better way to fix this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really important thing to understand about web programming is that **everything in the request is in the user's control**. The browser, or whatever software the user chooses, can send your server *whatever request they want*. All you can do is *read* that request, and decide what to do.

In this case, the browser is sending a cookie claiming they are a logged-in user; you have to decide whether to trust that claim.

You could make use of a *cryptographic signature*: when you set the cookie, include a signature using a private key that never leaves the server; then when a browser presents a cookie, verify the signature to see whether they are sending you back a value which you sent.

More simply, and more flexibly, you can make the cookie *an opaque random value*, and store information on the server associated with that value. This is the idea behind [PHP's session functionality](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php): a random identifier is generated, and sent to the browser in a cookie. When the browser sends back that random identifier, you can look up the information associated.

Sessions have a number of advantages, such as being able to store a larger amount of data; and reliably update or invalidate that data (you can *ask* the user's browser to delete a cookie, but you can't guarantee that it will do so, because *the user is in control*). Their main disadvantage is the requirement to store central state somewhere, which is tricky when "scaling out" to multiple web servers.